# How to get all the mainline streams of a project in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4python

I need to get all the mainline streams of a project. I tried this in the terminal

```
p4 streams -F "Type=mainline" //someproject
```

and got the following error,
`//ConMod - must refer to client 'dummy'`.
How can I resolve this and is there any better way. I want to this same task in p4Pyton

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct path for the stream depot (with a wildcard):

```
p4 streams -F "Type=mainline" //ConMod/...
```